# Why separate AD applications are created for every VSTS team project?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I created the user in Azure Active Directory. Next by using those credentials, I am logging into VSTS account and created few team projects. But for each VSTS team project a separate AD application also created in the azure portal automatically.

Can anyone suggest me what is the reason for creating the AD application of every VSTS team project?

Comment: The team AD account should be running the builds and releases against azure? look at it as a service account.

Comment: @MarcusHöglund, yes,the AD account should be running the builds and releases. can you please explain more details.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes Starian, Actually that is not issue just for knowing reason of creating AD application for every VSTS team project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you created new Azure service endpoints for these team project, with automated way to create azure service endpoint, it will create new AD applications and the name likes `{vsts account}-{team project}-{subscription id}`.

You can refer to these blog to create azure service endpoint manually: [Automating Azure Resource Group deployment using a Service Principal in Visual Studio Online: Build/Release Management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/)